# diplay: fixed doesnt seem to work on a button

Tags: html, css

I have no idea why but this button just wont `display: fixed;` I have no idea what to try

```
   <div>

     <button class="drop_buttton">DROPDOWN</button>  

   </div>
```

.

```
 .drop_buttton {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  display: fixed;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 2%;
 }
```

Comment: You'll want to make it a habit to review documentation for this type of thing when you hit a snag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: thank you a lot now i feel really dumb aspecialy by the enourmeus amout of time i spent trying to fix that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such property like `display: fixed`, rather use `position: fixed`